# Algorithm code for Drazin and Bott-Duffin inverse (Matlab or C)

Tags: linear-algebra

I could find the common Moore-Penrose algorithm, but I couldn't find the Drazin or the Bott-Duffin generalised inverse, except for some very specific cases, useless for my studying purposes.

Is there a Matlab or C code for at least one of the two algorithms?

Answer (score 1):

The following paper describes how to modify Gauss-Jordan elimination to form Drazin inverse:

- K. M. Anstreicher, U. G. Rothblum, "[Using Gauss-Jordan elimination to compute the index, generalized nullspaces, and Drazin inverse](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(87)90219-9)," *Linear Algebra Appl.*, vol. 85, pp. 221-239, Jan. 1987.

I am not aware of a Matlab or C library that implemented that approach; however, the algorithm inside this particular paper does not seem to be too hard to be implemented.

Also, this paper has several papers discussing efficient algorithms to compute Drazin inverse inside the references.

I was also able to find [a similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908731/drazin-inverse-of-a-matrix), where one of the answers cites [another paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0096-3003(02)00814-7) **that has a Matlab code** for computing Drazin inverses of two-variable polynomial matrices, which is probably an overkill. As I was reading this paper, it is based on the Greville algorithm for finding Drazin inverse (the algorithm listed there is also pretty straightforward):

- T. N. E. Greville, "[The Souriau-Frame algorithm and the Drazin pseudoinverse](https://doi.org/10.1016/0024-3795(73)90021-9),"  *Linear Algebra Appl.*, vol. 6, pp. 205-208, Feb. 1973

While doing a literature review, I was also able to find the other paper **that has Mathematica code** for finding Drazin inverse for polynomial matrices inside. Again, it is probably an overkill for you; though, I guess, the modifications and optimizations that you can do for your constant matrix case should not be too drastic:

- M. D. Petkovich, P. S. Stanimirovich, "[Interpolation algorithm for computing Drazin inverse of polynomial matrices](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.laa.2006.11.011)," *Linear Algebra Appl.*, vol. 422, no. 2-3, pp. 526-539, Apr. 2007

The thing I am the least confident about is a Matlab package for finding Drazin inverse using gradient neural network [GNN_Drazin](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/59444-gnn-drazin). I personally do not have enough knowledge to either judge how feasible is this numerical approach using neural networks, nor the quality of the package itself.